# Does linking C with C++ avoid undefined behavior that is legal in C but not C++?

Tags: c++, c, language-lawyer

If you have a C file, compiled with a C compiler and have defined behavior for C but not C++, can you link it with a C++ file and not have undefined behavior?

in blah.c (the file compiled as C)

```
struct x {
    int blah;
    char buf[];
};

extern char * get_buf(struct x * base);
extern struct x * make_struct(int blah, int size);
```

blah_if.h

```
extern "C"
{
    struct x;

    char * get_buf(struct x * base);
    struct x * make_struct(int blah, int size);
}
```

some_random.cpp (Compiled with a C++ compiler)

```
#include "blah_if.h"

...

x * data=make_struct(7, 12);
std::strcpy(get_buf(data), "hello");
```

Is using the defined behavior in C's flexible array member in a file compiled with a C compiler, defined behavior when used by a file compiled as C++ and linked with the object from the C compiler?

*Note that because a C compiler is used and `struct x` is opaque, this is different than:*

[Does extern C with C++ avoid undefined behavior that is legal in C but not C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31881811/does-extern-c-with-c-avoid-undefined-behavior-that-is-legal-in-c-but-not-c)

Comment: As long as well defined source code went into the relevant compiler you're fine linking the object code.

Comment: @GlennTeitelbaum You should have improved your original question in that direction, instead of posting a new one.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ  Can you and Drew Dormann please discuss, He said leave that question as extern C, you are saying edit thart question to be linkage
There are two questions, extern "C" and linkage, and drew felt I asked the former and should leave it

Comment: I for one think it should be two separate questions as he is asking about two techniques.

Comment: @this I'm actually doing so, you may vote to reopen if you like.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I did suggest the action that Glenn took.  If you're interested, see my comments on the linked question.

Comment: @GlennTeitelbaum It's about linkage primarily. See this related:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18877437/undefined-reference-to-errors-when-linking-static-c-library-with-c-code/18879053#18879053

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ no its about UB and its relation to linkage, not name mangling

Comment: @GlennTeitelbaum `extern "C" ` requires unmangled c symbols, so you can be sure that it was compiled using plain c. If the c Compiler, that was used to compile that code, guarantees the behavior is defined, it will still be defined when linked to c++ code that would consider such statement UB.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As Raymond has already said, this is implementation-defined at the formal, language level.

But it's important to remember what your compiled code *is*. It's not C++ code any more, nor is it C code. The rules about the behaviour of code in those languages apply to code written in those languages. They are taken into consideration during the parsing and translation process. But, once your code has been translated into assembly, or machine code, or whatever else you translated it to, *those rules no longer apply*.

So it's effectively meaningless to ask whether compiled C code has UB. If you had a well-defined C program, and compiled it, *that's that*. You're out of the realm of being able to discuss whether the compiled program is well-defined or not. It's a meaningless distinction, unless you have somehow managed to generate a program that is dictated to have UB by the specification for your assembly or machine language dialect.

The upshot of all this is that the premise of your question is unsound. You can't "avoid undefined behaviour" when linking to the compiled result of a C program, because the very notion of "undefined behaviour" does not exist there. But, **as long as the original source code was well-defined when you translated it, you will be fine**.

Comment: Eloquently put. Did you mean to imply that there can be no problems once you have reached the target language? Linking between different calling conventions probably qualifies as a variety of undefined behaviour

Comment: This describes one model of compilation, but not the only one. Another model is link-time code generation - under this model, source code gets compiled to an intermediate language, and it is at link time that actual assembly code gets generated. That intermediate language could have UB.

Comment: @RaymondChen: Where is this model defined, and is it within the scope of either C or C++?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit The standard does not address when code generation occurs. It is an implementation detail. Both [gcc](http://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/LinkTimeOptimization) and [Visual Studio](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xbf3tbeh(VS.80).aspx) support it. It sometimes goes by the name "whole program optimization".

Answer (score 19):

The behavior is implementation-defined.

> **[dcl.link]** Linkage from C++ to objects defined in other languages and to objects defined in C++ from other languages is implementation-defined and language-dependent.

It continues:

> Only where the object layout strategies of two language implementations are similar enough can such linkage be achieved.

That sentence in the standard really should be an annotation, since it doesn't specify what counts as "similar enough".

Comment: I think this is the correct answer, and at least the safest, but I can't imagine how the subroutine as compiled by the C compiler could break just because the entry was from c++ (with extern 'C' to use C calling conventions etc.)

Comment: odd that the language supports `extern C` for linkage, but doesn't count C as a defined linkage

Comment: I'm not sure this quote from the spec is relevant.  I see linkage from C++ to functions written in C.  The C++ spec requires this to work.  I don't see any objects being linked.

Comment: @arx do you have the part of the spec that requires linkage from C++ to functions written in C to work, if so, that would be a good answer

Comment: Even if functions are exempt from the quoted section of [dcl.link], I don't see any requirement that `struct x*` in C and `struct x*` in C++ be identically-represented.